# Integrating $∫\frac{1}{g-kv^2}dv$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$∫\frac{1}{g-kv^2}dv$

If I assume that both $g,k>0$ or both $g,k<0$, I see that I can use fractional decomposition and maybe a few trig tricks to solve the question. However, normally, I see this integral is for when $g$ is acceleration due to gravity, which is negative, while $k$ is a positive constant (usually representing air resistance).

Thus, $g<0$ and $k>0$. I was wondering if there's any way to solve the integral when this is the case.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried trigonometric substitution?

Answer (score 3):

In this case $g\neq 0$ and $\frac{k}{g}<0$ then 
$$\int \frac{1}{g-kv^2}dv = \frac{1}{g}\int\frac{1}{1-\frac{k}{g}v^2}dv = \frac{1}{g}\int \frac{1}{1+\left(\sqrt{-\frac{k}{g}}v\right)^2}dv = $$

By substitution $u=\sqrt{-\frac{k}{g}}v$ and $du=\sqrt{-\frac{k}{g}}dv$

$$ = \frac{1}{g}\sqrt{-\frac{g}{k}}\int \frac{1}{1+u^2}du =$$

the constant $g<0$ then $\frac{1}{g}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{g^2}}$

$$ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{g^2}}\sqrt{-\frac{g}{k}}\int \frac{1}{1+u^2}du = -\sqrt{-\frac{1}{kg}}tan^{-1}(u)+C= -\sqrt{-\frac{1}{kg}}tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{-\frac{k}{g}}v\right)+C$$

Comment: Your final answer is not quite correct. First, in the second last part on the right, the square root sign should not include the $v$ factor. More importantly, you forgot to account for the $\sqrt{-\frac{k}{g}}$ multiplier of $v$ in the denominator, as well as not provide the constant of integration. Taking a factor of $-\frac{1}{k}$ out & using Wikipedia's [List of integrals of rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions) result of $\int \frac{1}{x^2+a^2}dx = \frac{1}{a}\text{arctan}\frac{x}{a} + C$, or doing as you did & using a substitution ...

Comment: (cont.) like $u = \sqrt{-\frac{k}{g}}v$, you should end up with something like $-\sqrt{-\frac{1}{kg}}\text{arctan}\left(\sqrt{-\frac{k}{g}}v\right) + C$. Also, I forgot earlier to mention the square root in your final RHS term should not include the $v$ either.

Comment: hmm. I wrote and solved wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Let $G=-g>0$.Then

$$I=-\int\frac{dv}{G+kv^2}=-\frac1k \int\frac{dv}{v^2+\frac Gk}$$

Compare
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2+A^2}\overset{x=A\tan t}{\longmapsto} ?$$